# dynamic id for li mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $('li').mouseout(function () {
        divId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).css('background', 'url(assets/images/clients/logo/' + divId + '.jpg)');
    });
    $('li').mouseover(function () {
        divId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).css('background', 'url(assets/images/clients/logo-gc/' + divId + '.jpg)');
    });
    $('li').load(function () {
        divId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).css('background', 'url(assets/images/clients/logo/' + divId + '.jpg)');
    });
</script>
```

What mistake did I make? The image is not displaying at startup after page load...

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="i1"></li>   
    <li id="i2"></li>
    <li id="i3"></li>
    <li id="i4"></li>   
    <li id="i5"></li>
    <li id="i6"></li>
    <li id="i7"></li>   
    <li id="i8"></li>
</ul>
```

How do I load the default image on li.load() after page load?

Comment: By the way, it seems like you are not declaring `divId`. Make sure that you declare it. For example use `var divId;` or `var divId = $(this).attr('id');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
   $('li').each(function(){
     var divId = $(this).attr('id');
     $(this).css('background-image', 'url(assets/images/clients/logo/'+divId+'.jpg)');
   });
});
```

Comment: May I know the reason for Downvoting?

Answer (score 3):

Use `background-image` instead of `background` ,

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(assets/images/clients/logo/'+divId+'.jpg)');
```

To show image after page load use **[`$(document).ready(function(){   })`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)** handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('li').each(function(){
       $(this).css('background-image', 'url(assets/images/clients/logo/' + this.id + '.jpg)');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `<li>` elements don't have `jQuery.load` method (in the context you're trying to get here). The `jQuery.load` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) says clearly:

> *This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object*

You should bind the event to the document load. The simple shortcut for this is `$(function() {...})`, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'url(assets/images/clients/logo/'+ this.id +'.jpg)');
    });
});
```